# should I create a counter column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

Optimization was never one of my expertise. I have `users` table. every user has many followers. So now I'm wondering if I should use a counter column in case that some user has a million followers. So instead of counting a whole table of relations, shouldn't I use a counter?

I'm working with SQL database.

**Update 1**

Right now I'm only writing the way I should build my site. I haven't write the code yet. I don't know if I'll have slow performance, that's why I'm asking you.

Comment: I don't know, should you? Are you having performance problems right now? Counts are generally very quick operations.

Comment: Do you have particular queries you are or are thinking of running?  What is the issue with performance?

Comment: What are you using the count for? Is it essential to the application or for reporting?

Comment: If you really need that count column, either manage it with triggers, or as "computed column" (or whatever SQL Server calls it.)

Comment: “We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time; premature optimization is the root of all evil” — Donald E. Knuth, Structured Programming with go to Statements. [Note:  I'm not quite sure about *all evil*, but that is the quote.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should certainly **not** introduce a counter **right away**. The counter is redundant data and it will complicate everything. You will have to master the additional complexity and it'll slow down the development process.

Better start with a normalized model and see how it works. If you really run into performance problems, solve it then then.

Remember: premature optimization is the root of all evils.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good practice to avoid duplication of data, such as summarizing one data point in another data's table.

It depends on what this is for. If this is for reporting, speed is usually not an issue and you can use a join.

If it has to do with the application and you're running into performance issues with join or computed column, you may want to consider summary table generated on a schedule.

If you're not seeing a performance issue, leave it alone.